# Any video lectures on conventional analytical geometry?

Tags: analytic-geometry, online-resources

Hi this question is kind of a natural offshoot [to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165852/a-good-open-source-book-on-analytic-geometry/169378#169378)  My topic covers very conventional topics like :

> Cartesian and Polar Coordinates in 3 Dim, second Degree eqns in 3 vars, reduction to canonical forms, straight lines, shortest distance between 2 skew lines, Plane, sphere, cone, cylinder, paraboloid, ellipsoid,hyperboloid of one and two sheets and their properties.

I had been working on my own for some time, but a paucity of time and the book being slightly dry has led me to this point.

Is there any repository of video lectures to help me through stuff like ellipsoid, paraboloid etc... I am having a bit of difficulty in putting together the large themes (no book does that, its my own approach: you can say a mental archive/model of the big ideas. I have often noticed doing this leads me to internalise things better) in my brain, and I think listening to a video lecture might help(coming second to a one to one class).

Comment: I don't know if they have what you're looking for, but I'd like to point out [Khan Academdy](http://www.khanacademy.org/).

Comment: yes, I did. And no they dont have on 3d coordinate geometry

Answer (score 1):

Try:

https://sites.google.com/a/ncps-k12.org/multivariable-calculus/videos

You might also try Khan Academy, but I have not checked that.

Regards -A

Comment: Nice suggestions! $\Large \;\uparrow\;$ needed!

Comment: @amWhy: thx! You were right, very slow night. Make sure to get enough rest so you get over that bug! Regards

Answer (score 0):

Would either of these work?

- [Quadric Surfaces](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3a3CgTewqjs)
- [An Introduction to Quadric Surfaces](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c1mc1o66ko4)