# A book on analytic geometry

Tags: geometry, reference-request, analytic-geometry, book-recommendation

It's easy to find good recommendation for books here for any subject other than analytic geometry ,therefore I'd like to ask for any suggestion of analytic geometry books ,the only  charactrestic I'm looking for is a somewhat visual expostion.

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165852/a-good-open-source-book-on-analytic-geometry?rq=1) for a start. Also, there are a lot of textbooks out there with the title *Calculus and Analytic Geometry*, in case you're interested.

Comment: The answer would depend on your needs - whether you need to supplement a class in analytic geometry or you want to learn analytic geometry for further studies of modern mathematics.