# What are the best books for analytical geometry UG level? and substantially helpful for GMAT prep?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, book-recommendation

I need a good book for studying analytical geometry which involves 2d geometry , conic sections, 3d geometry, quadroids, conicoids, locus etc at UG level and helpful for GMAT prep also.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should use the `book-recommendation` tag.

Comment: You might want to provide more context on what types of problems you're interested in.  Analytic geometry (even at the undergrad level) is not likely what you want for the GMAT (at least after a quick google search - perhaps I'm finding the wrong GMAT?).

Comment: I need it for a better understanding of these topics , a book every math student might recommend !

Comment: Most of these topics (conic sections, locus problems, conicoids, etc.) are not on the GMAT, and what is on the GMAT is at too low of a level for you to need a book (such as those I mentioned in my answer to [A good Open Source book on Analytic Geometry?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165852/a-good-open-source-book-on-analytic-geometry)). You would be better off with something like Manhattan Prep's [**Advanced GMAT Quant**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1935707159).

Answer (score 2):

There is no one such book but I will suggest you few books that will help you to learn and will help for GMAT.

1) Analytical Geometry: With the Properties of Conic Sections, and an Appendix, Constituting a Tract On Descriptive Geometry by John Narrien (2010 – Nabu Press)

2) Calculus with Analytical Geometry for the Technologies (Prentice Hall Series in Technical Mathematics) by Lawrence M. Clar and James A. Hart (1980 – Prentice Hall)

3) Analytical Geometry: Two and Three Dimensions by D. Chatterjee (2009 – Alpha Science International Limited)