# Geometry book suggestions

Tags: geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation

Could you list a few good books to study geometry that includes parabolas, ellipses, circles, hyperbolae (basically conic sections), as well as three dimensional geometry which could possibly lend some intuitive thinking about some abstract concepts while remaining linguistically simple as can? I know I could always pull out some results from Google but it doesn't hurt to get the latest opinion about the affair. I want to be thorough with the subject matter, from basics to general equations to questions and maybe every now and then, a few mind boggling observations that are hardly seen in school textbook, if you know what I mean. I am familiar with trigonometry, a bit of basic calculus, binomials and stuff. Cheers!

Comment: It might help if you specify what level of math you are lookong for... high school, ap, college, or even gtm? Or maybe just for fun?

Comment: Finney's 'Calculus and Analytic Geometry' covers these topics quite well.

Comment: @trisct I'm a highschool student looking to revise middle school geometry (like theorems and triangles with similar bases kind of things) as well as take it to the level of highschool and above, with trig etc.

Comment: @trisct and that you could say, I want to do for fun

Comment: @A.Goodier I'll give it a read.

Comment: See my answer to [A good Open Source book on Analytic Geometry?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/165870/13130). Many of these books are on the internet --- google the author and title with "archive.org". Two books that I especially recommend (I have original hard copy printed editions) are [**Elements of Analytical Geometry**](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.177084) by George Alexander Gibson and Peter Pinkerton (1911) and [**Plane and Solid Analytic Geometry**](https://archive.org/details/planeandsolidan02graugoog) by William Fogg Osgood and William Casper Graustein (1921).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the first chapter of 
"Geometry / David A. Brannan, Matthew F. Esplen, Jeremy J. Gray. – 2nd ed".