# A good book for conics?

Tags: reference-request, conic-sections, book-recommendation

I want to learn about conics, but I don't really like the chapter on our textbook or the calculus & analytic geometry book that I'm following.

Conics are so interesting, ellipse and hyperbola specially, needless to say. I've learned about Dandelin's theorem, which explains why slicing a cone with a slanted horizontal plane always cross sects the cone into an ellipse, of all shapes.

Which is really beautiful right? But our textbook ain't. I'd like to learn about conics from a book that covers super cool stuff like Dandelin's theorem and generalized [Dandelin's theorem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQa_tWZmlGs) (I don't really know much about conics other than that cool theorem haha) so I'm hoping you guys know such a book.

(Also, on a quick side note, I want to learn about hyperbolic functions and their inverses from a book that just doesn't discuss their derivatives and integrals; and approaches the concept like the unit circle definition for circular functions does. Any suggestion is appreciated.)

Comment: Hyperbolic functions by V.G Shervatov is a good book  about hyperbolic functions, it discuses the geometrical definition  etc and it's short, it only has 61 pages.

Comment: See the books I cited [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/165870/13130), along with [**Elements of Analytical Geometry**](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.177084/page/n3/mode/2up) by George Alexander Gibson and Peter Pinkerton (1911) and [**Plane and Solid Analytic Geometry**](https://archive.org/details/planeandsolidan02graugoog) by William Fogg Osgood and William Casper Graustein (1921). The last two books are especially complete. Also, [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22analytical+conics%22+archive.org) (also, replace "analytical" with "analytic").

Comment: For hyperbolic functions, try [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hyperbolic+functions%22+archive.org).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I see you're suggesting books on analytic geometry. My intuition too, says, conics are an integral part of this particular branch of mathematics. But analytic geometry books that take on a calculus approach just suck at demonstrating the beauty of conics to the readers (I personally find it so). I guess I'm looking for books that are euclidean in nature (if you know about Dandelin's theorem, you know what I mean), but I'd like to read ones that follow the old style without old literature, old literature is just... so hard to read  Do you think your books fit my description?

Comment: Try [geometrical conics](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22geometrical+conics%22+archive.org) and this [google books search](https://www.google.com/search?q=conics&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899). For something relatively recent, the best thing I can think of is [**Conics**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0883853353) by Keith Kendig (2005; [review](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/conics); [more info.](https://academic.csuohio.edu/kendig_k/conics_pdfs.html)) --- looking at this book now (I got a copy a few years ago), this seems pretty close to what you're looking for.

Comment: You can consider reading a very good books on conics by Akopyan and Zaslavsky, available here: http://geometry.ru/books/conic_e.pdf

Comment: @Intelligentipauca What a beautiful recommendation. By the way, I recently  saw your brilliant geometric solution in a problem that involves tangents of parabolas (Arztz parabolas). What books do you recommend that involves that kind of problems and solutions?

Comment: @AbrahamHernández Most ruler-and-compass construction involving conics (and much more) are given in Eagles' book ["Constructive geometry of plane curves"](https://archive.org/details/constructivegeom00eagluoft)

Comment: I am curious what book did you end using and did you find what you wanted? I have the same problem btw

Comment: @Ahmed I took a liking to Conics by Keith Kendig, but all the suggestions are great honestly you should check them out

Comment: @HERO do you have pdf file of it ?

Comment: @Ahmed Unfortunately I could only manage a .djvu file